# How to draw a square on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, draw

I'm trying to draw squares at the corners of a canvas. The top ones work but I should be able to draw the third square which I have partially drawn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/javascript">

  function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }

  var t = getRandomInt(10);

    function draw() {
      function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      }

      var t = getRandomInt(10);
      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        setInterval(myTimer, t*100);

      function myTimer() {
        var i = 0;
        var x = window.innerWidth;
        var y = window.innerHeight;
        y = y + 100;
//draw crosshair
   console.log("x = "+ x);
   console.log("y = "+ y);
   console.log("i = "+ i);

ctx.beginPath();
var crosshairlength = 20;
var lengthxminus = crosshairlength;
var lengthxplus = crosshairlength;
var lengthyminus = crosshairlength;
var lengthyplus = crosshairlength;

//horizontal line
ctx.moveTo((x/2)-lengthxminus, y/2);
ctx.lineTo((x/2)+lengthxplus, y/2);

//vertical line
ctx.moveTo(x/2, (y/2)-lengthyminus);
ctx.lineTo(x/2, (y/2)+lengthyplus);


var t = 10;

//top left

ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(t,0);
ctx.lineTo(t,t);
ctx.lineTo(0,t);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);

//top right

ctx.moveTo(x-t,0);
ctx.lineTo(x,0);
ctx.lineTo(x,t);
ctx.lineTo(x-t,t);
ctx.lineTo(x-t,0);

//bottom right

ctx.moveTo(x-t,y-t);
ctx.lineTo(x,y-t);
ctx.lineTo(x,y);

//bottom left

ctx.stroke();
}
i++;
   }
}
  </script>
 </head>

 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="1846" height="768"></canvas>

 </body>
</html>
```

Either the canvas is the not the size of the viewport or I am misunderstanding the coordinate system which I believe has the positive y-axis going down and the origin is in the top left.

Answer (score 0):

`window.innerWidth`  and `window.innerHeight` represent the width and height of the viewport. Your <canvas> width and height are set by its `width` and `height` attributes.

If you want the canvas to be the size of the viewport, change these attributes, though changing these attributes come with great side-effects like reassigning a new pixel buffer, and clearing all the properties of the attached context, so it's better to do so only when really needed:

```js
if (canvas.width !== x) {
  canvas.width = x;
}
if (canvas.height !== y) {
  canvas.height = y;
}
```

And if you wanted to use the size of the canvas rather than the one of the viewport, then you want

```js
function myTimer() {
  var i = 0;
  var x = canvas.width;
  var y = canvas.height;
```